# How can I do this with LINQ?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

All I'm after doing is this:

```
SELECT CallTypeID, Count(CallTypeID) as NumberOfCalls
FROM [Helpdesk_HR].[dbo].[CallHeader]
WHERE CallHeader.DateOpened <= GETDATE()-7
GROUP BY CallTypeID
```

in LINQ. But I can't work out a way of doing it and getting it to work. I would use Linqer, but my company won't pay for it at present.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm sure the answer is obvious. It's just been one of those days today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var callGroups = from ch in CallHeader
        where ch.YourDate <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)
        group ch by ch.CallTypeID into grp
        select new { CallTypeID = grp.Key, Cnt = grp.Count() };
```

I haven't tested so syntax might be off.

Comment: I'm working with VB, and I've converted most of it, but I'm having trouble with the .Key in the line: Select New With {.CallTypeID = grp.Key, .Cnt = grp.Count()}.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query = from call in context.CallHeader
            where call.DateOpened <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7)
            group call by call.CallTypeId into grouped
            select new { CallTypeId = grouped.Key, Count = grouped.Count() };
```

The `DateTime.Today` bit may be slightly off - it depends on things like how your dates are stored in the database. You may want to work out the date *before* the query and then just use "`where call.DateOpened <= limit`" or something like that.